# Creating a Spark exists user defined function that works like the Scala Array#exists function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Scala has an Array#exists function that works like this:

```
Array(1, 2, 5).exists(_ % 2 == 0) // true
```

I'd like to create a Spark exists function that works similarly.  Suppose we have the following `sourceDF`:

```
+---------+
|     nums|
+---------+
|[1, 4, 9]|
|[1, 3, 5]|
+---------+
```

I'd like to be able to write something like this:

```
val actualDF = sourceDF.withColumn(
  "nums_has_even",
  exists(col("nums"), (x: Int) => x % 2 == 0)
)
```

Here's the code I wrote:

```
def existsInt(arr: Array[Int], f: (Int => Boolean)): Boolean = {
  arr.exists(f(_))
}

val exists = udf[Boolean, Array[Int], (Int => Boolean)](existsInt)
```

I understand why my code isn't working.  UDFs require column arguments and an anonymous function isn't a Column object.  Wrapping the anonymous function in `lit` didn't work:

```
exists(col("nums"), lit((x: Int) => x % 2 == 0)) // doesn't work
```

How can I get this code working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close:

```
def existsInt(f: (Int => Boolean)) = udf {
  (arr: Seq[Int]) => arr.exists(f(_))  // Not Array!
}
```

Usage:

```
existsInt((x: Int) => x % 2 == 0)(col("nums"))
```

You can even:

```
scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def exists[T : TypeTag](f: (T => Boolean)) = udf[Boolean, Seq[T]]{
  (arr: Seq[T]) => arr.exists(f(_))  // Not Array!
}

exists[Int]((x: Int) => x % 2 == 0).apply(col("nums"))
```